# Why is there no flatten() method in the Stream API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

The following two code snippets yield the same result.

With `flatMap`:

```
Stream.iterate(2, n -> n + 4)
            .flatMap(n -> Stream.of(n, -(n + 2)));
```

With `map` followed by `flatMap` using `identity`:

```
Stream.iterate(2, n -> n + 4)
            .map(n -> Stream.of(n, -(n + 2)))
            .flatMap(Function.identity());
```

So it would seem natural to include a no-arg `flatten` method in the `Stream` interface (like in Scala's [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)), to allow the previous example to be written as:

```
Stream.iterate(2, n -> n + 4)
            .map(n -> Stream.of(n, -(n + 2)))
            .flatten();
```

So why is there no `flatten()` method in the `Stream` API?

Comment: The API is already fairly bloated. This would be an unnecessary addition.

Comment: I think this question misses the point. Basic API design says put in only as little to achieve what you want to achieve. And as it is possible, there is no reason for a flatten() method. Just imagine putting every possible use case as a dedicated method in the API. It would get bloated pretty quickly.

Comment: I don't think that API bloating is a valid point. As I mentioned in the question there is `flatten` in Scala (which also has `flatMap`). I could even turn the argument and say, okay, then why include `flatMap` if the problem can be solved by combining `map` and `flatten`. Of course, the reason why `flatMap` exists is performance and convenience. That's  the trade-off between minimalistic API and a convenient one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `flatten` method couldn't be implemented in Java. It would only be callable on a `Stream<? extends Stream<?>>` but there is no way to determine whether `T extends Stream<R>` for some type `R`.

If you look at the method signature in Scala:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Stream[B]
```

It actually takes an implicit evidence parameter that the type `A` is a collection of some type `B`.

The `flatMap` method in Java takes a function `T -> Stream<? extends R>`:

```
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

So we know that it can be flattened to `Stream<R>`.

A static implementation of `flatten` is possible:

```
static <R> Stream<R> flatten(Stream<? extends Stream<? extends R>> stream) {
    return stream.flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Stream to be a monad, it's not enough to randomly define "flatten", or "join" or whatever you name it. There are monadic laws. Unit law. Associativity law. The one that is listed here, "enumerate the first one, then switch to the second" does not preserve the unit.

The only monadic "flatten" for a Stream I can imagine is this:

- the first element from the first element;
- the second element from the second element;
- and so on.

This is a monad (because it's derived from the diagonal ℕ → ℕ×ℕ.

Anything else is probably not a monad. It would be nice to see another example.